# How to use two sets of data for drawing graph using MPAndroidChart in Android

Tags: android, charts, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I was trying to use two sets of data while using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

```
val values1 = ArrayList<Entry>()
values1.add(Entry(3f,2f))
values1.add(Entry(3.5f,4f))
values1.add(Entry(4f,3f))
val values = ArrayList<Entry>()
values.add(Entry(3f,2f))
values.add(Entry(3.5f,4f))
values.add(Entry(4f,3f))
values.add(Entry(4.5f,6f))
values.add(Entry(5f,10f))
values.add(Entry(5.5f,4f))
values.add(Entry(6f,3f))
```

And drawing the Line graph

```
var set1:LineDataSet
var set2:LineDataSet
set1 = LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1")
set2 = LineDataSet(values1, "DataSet 2")

set1.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
set1.cubicIntensity = 0.2f
set1.setDrawFilled(true)
set1.setDrawCircles(false)
set1.lineWidth = 1.8f
set1.color = ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorAccent)
set1.fillColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorAccent)
set1.fillAlpha = 100
set1.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
//set1.setFillFormatter { dataSet, dataProvider -> chart.axisLeft.minWidth }

set2.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
set2.cubicIntensity = 0.2f
set2.setDrawFilled(true)
set2.setDrawCircles(false)
set2.lineWidth = 1.8f
set2.color = ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorPrimary)
set2.fillColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorPrimary)
set2.fillAlpha = 100
set2.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
//set2.setFillFormatter { dataSet, dataProvider -> chart.axisLeft.zeroLineWidth }

// create a data object with the data sets
val list= mutableListOf<LineDataSet>()
list.add(set1)
list.add(set2)
val data = LineData(list as List<ILineDataSet>?)
data.setValueTextSize(9f)
data.setDrawValues(false)

// set data
chart.data = data
```

The outcome is like this
[image]

I just want to improve or smooth the graph of set2 [arrow marked] so that the line exactly overlaps the set1 and hide that part of data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, the mode needs to be changed.

```
set.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
```